# How to change MenuItem icon in ActionBar programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-menu

How to change MenuItem icon in ActionBar programmatically? I tried to use

```
MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.action_settings);
menuItem.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
```

but it doesn't work.
This is my code:

MainActivity

```
package com.test;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.action_settings);
                menuItem.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/action_settings"
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

activity_main

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="Set icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the exception that i've had after running:

```
MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.action_settings);


11-09 19:52:40.471    1735-1735/com.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView
            at com.test.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:19)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 298, accepted):

You can't use `findViewById()` on menu items in `onCreate()` because the menu layout isn't inflated yet. You could create a global Menu variable and initialize it in the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and then use it in your `onClick()`.

```
private Menu menu;
```

In your `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

```
this.menu = menu;
```

In your button's `onClick()` method

```
menu.getItem(0).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```

Comment: what about in a fragment, where there is no onCreateOptionsMenu() ?

Comment: You probably need to call a method on your Activity from your Fragment

Comment: @LalithMohan, I tried the same thing, but it doesn't work. I could though change the font color of the title of the menu-item, i am unable to change the icon. I've posted my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36716450/setting-icons-to-the-menu-items

Comment: I got "getDrawable() is deprecated" error message.  Possible solutions are in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22

Comment: getDrawable is deprecated. Anyone got a new solution?

Comment: Why is this answer upvoted and accepted? "You can't use findViewById() on menu items in onCreate() because the menu layout isn't inflated yet." The OP didn't use findViewById() on menu items in onCreate(), but in **onClick()**. AFAIK onClick() shouldn't get called until well after the menu is inflated. Moreover, the ClassCastException is due to a different problem, namely that the OP is trying to cast a ActionMenuItemView to a MenuItem.

Answer (score 54):

Lalith's answer is correct.

You may also try this approach:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    });

 @Override
 public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuItem settingsItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
    // set your desired icon here based on a flag if you like
    settingsItem.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_launcher)); 

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
 }
```

Answer (score 10):

This works for me. It should be in your `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` method  `item.setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon);`

Answer (score 6):

Here is how i resolved this:

1 -  create a Field Variable like: `private Menu mMenuItem;`

2 - override the method invalidateOptionsMenu():

```
@Override
public void invalidateOptionsMenu() {
    super.invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

3 - call the method `invalidateOptionsMenu()` in your `onCreate()`

4 - add `mMenuItem = menu` in your `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.webview_menu, menu);
    mMenuItem = menu;
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

5 - in the method `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` change the icon you want like this:

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.R.id.action_settings:
            mMenuItem.getItem(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher); // to change the fav icon
            //Toast.makeText(this, " " + mMenuItem.getItem(0).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); <<--- this to check if the item in the index 0 is the one you are looking for
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: let's say I have 5 items, I need to change the icons when clicked...but when I click the next item, the prev item's icon needs to be restored..how to do that??

Answer (score 4):

Instead of getViewById(), use

```
MenuItem item = getToolbar().getMenu().findItem(Menu.FIRST);
```

replacing the `Menu.FIRST` with your menu item id.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this problem this way:

In `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
this.menu = menu;
this.menu.add("calendar");
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
imageView.setMinimumHeight(128);
imageView.setMinimumWidth(128);
imageView.setImageDrawable(yourDrawable);
MenuItem item = this.menu.getItem(0);
item.setActionView(imageView);
```

in `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
if (item.getOrder() == 0) {
    //TODO
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Kotlin version:**

```
toolbar.menu.findItem(R.id.notification).icon =
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.ic_notification)

toolbar.menu.findItem(R.id.notification).isVisible = true
```

Answer (score 0):

to use in `onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)`
just do `invalidateOptionsMenu();
item.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_outline_24px));`

Answer (score -1):

**Its Working**

```
      MenuItem tourchmeMenuItem; // Declare Global .......

 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
 {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false);
        tourchmeMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.done);
        return true;
 }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    case R.id.done:
                       if(LoginPreferences.getActiveInstance(CustomViewFinderScannerActivity.this).getIsFlashLight()){
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                mScannerView.setFlash(false);
                                LoginPreferences.getActiveInstance(CustomViewFinderScannerActivity.this).setIsFlashLight(false);
                                tourchmeMenuItem.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.torch_white_32));
                            }
                        }else {
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                mScannerView.setFlash(true);
                                LoginPreferences.getActiveInstance(CustomViewFinderScannerActivity.this).setIsFlashLight(true);
                                tourchmeMenuItem.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.torch_cross_white_32));
                            }
                        }
                        break;

}
```