# Good practice to do ActionBar icon toggle

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I am have an ActionBar with some menu items that are icons.
And what I want is to toggle between two drawables.

This is what I have done so far:

```
if(id == R.id.shift_day){
if(DoN==0){
item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_weather_day);
shift="shift night";
DoN=1;
onStart();
}
if(DoN==1){
item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_weather_night);
shift="shift day";
DoN=0;
onStart();
}
}
```

This does not work so good because it changes the icon once and never back again.

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882443/how-to-change-menuitem-icon-in-actionbar-programatically

Comment: My code is inside the **onOptionsItemSelected** already so dont know what to do here.

Comment: on which condition supposed to change icon ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are setting DoN=0 inside onStart() method. Try removing that and instead put return true;
Your code if DoN=0 then it first sets DoN=1 then it matches the second block and enters there and set DoN=0 back.
Try this:

```
    if(id == R.id.shift_day){
        if(DoN==0){
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_weather_day);
            shift="shift night";
            DoN=1;
        }
        else if(DoN==1){
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_weather_night);
            shift="shift day";
            DoN=0;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: This worked really well. Even with the **onStart** thats needed to reaload data from Firebase into a listview depending on the **shift**.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare DoN as a static variable and save this DoN variable to [SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851560/how-to-use-sharedpreferences) to remember which state we gonna use for later. When you restart the program, get this variable from SharedPreferences and then [set  icon for menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882443/how-to-change-menuitem-icon-in-actionbar-programatically) :)