# Apply image to a menu item dynamically

Tags: java, android, xml, android-image

I'm trying to add an image to menu item programmatically using glide.

**main_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_profile_pic"
    android:icon="@mipmap/profile_pic"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

**Java**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions.placeholder(R.mipmap.profile_pic);
    requestOptions.error(R.mipmap.profile_pic);

    MenuItem itemProfilePic = menu.getItem(0);
    //View view = findViewById(R.id.action_profile_pic);

    if (savedProfilePic != null) {
        Glide.with(this)
                .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
                .load(Uri.parse(savedProfilePic))
                .into(itemProfilePic);
    }
    return true;
```

However, I can't use this approach since the resource is a MenuItem and not an ImageView. Casting it to an ImageView also doesn't work.

How can I achieve the desired result, given that the image is not in the drawables folder, its set by the user, hence below approach also can't be used:

`itemProfilePic.setActionView(savedProfilePic);` Takes in an integer value

**Final result**

[image]

Comment: so basically you require the complete row of menu to be custom or just image?

Comment: I've edited the post, custom image at the end

Comment: @lbra, try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882443/how-to-change-menuitem-icon-in-actionbar-programmatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change MenuItem icon in ActionBar programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882443/how-to-change-menuitem-icon-in-actionbar-programmatically)

Comment: @lbra try above suggested answer if that works for you

Comment: @KOTIOS no it does not, my image is not in the drawable its applied by the user(custom)

Comment: @Hanzala it's not a duplicate, with the suggested answer, the OP has their image inside the drawable, unlike in my case

Comment: @lbra Is menu contains only 1 item with custom image? In that case why dont you have custom toolbar with imageview on right side?

Comment: @Ibra Then what's difference in your question? even you are setting an image which is saved ... and could be converted as drawable....

Answer (score 1):

The `MenuItem` Interface has a method: [`setIcon(Drawable d)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)).

1. Get a reference to the `MenuItem` you want to update.
2. Convert the image you want to set into a [`BitmapDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable).
3. Adjust the drawable as desired and set via `MenuItem.setIcon()` method.

It seems you can also implement [custom target](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/targets.html#custom-targets) from the image loader library you are using. The custom target can wrap a `MenuItem`.

**Note:**
Since you are inflating an XML menu, chances are it will be refreshed. Therefore, perform the image icon update after inflating the XML as well.

Answer (score 0):

make a custom toolbar and then you can use the image view to change image dynamically

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:background="@color/primaryColor"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_perm_24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```